# Помогите найти контрольные тесты для программы

Tags: c++, map, структуры-данных, set

Задача "Выборы США". Мог бы её тупо скопировать, но решил сделать сам, убил кучу времени, и открытые тесты прога проходит, по времени тоже, но при проверке пишет неверный ответ. Помогите найти случаи, при которых прога неправильный ответ будет выдавать.

Задача:
Выборы в США
Как известно, в США президент выбирается не прямым голосованием, а путём двухуровневого голосования. Сначала проводятся выборы в каждом штате, и определяется победитель выборов в данном штате. Затем проводятся государственные выборы: на этих выборах каждый штат имеет определённое число голосов — число выборщиков от этого штата. На практике все выборщики от штата голосуют в соответствии с результатами голосования внутри штата, то есть на заключительной стадии выборов в голосовании участвуют штаты, имеющие различное число голосов.

На этот раз вам известно число выборщиков от каждого штата США и результаты голосования каждого гражданина США (а также в каком штате проживает данный гражданин).

Вам необходимо подвести результаты голосования: сначала определить результаты голосования в каждом штате и определить, за кого из кандидатов отданы голоса выборщиков данного штата. Далее необходимо подвести результаты голосования выборщиков по всем штатам.

Входные данные

Первая строка входных данных содержит количество штатов в США N (1≤N≤100000). Далее идёт N строк, описывающих штаты США, каждая строка состоит из названия штата и числа выборщиков от этого штата. На следующей строке задано число M (1≤M≤100000)— количество проголосовавших на выборах. В следующих M строках идут записи результатов голосования по каждому из участников голосования. Одна строка соответствует одному избирателю. Записи имеют следующий вид: название штата, имя кандидата, за которого проголосовал данный избиратель. Названия штатов и имена кандидатов не содержат пробелов.

Выходные данные

Выведите список кандидатов, упорядоченный по убыванию числа голосов выборщиков, полученных за данного кандидата, а при равенстве числа голосов выборщиков — в лексикографическом порядке. После имени кандидата выведите число набранных им голосов.

Если в каком-либо штате два или более кандидатов набрали одинаковое число голосов, то все голоса выборщиков этого штата получает наименьший в лексикографическом порядке кандидат из числа победителей в этом штате.

Гарантируется, что в каждом штате проголосовал хотя бы один избиратель.

```
Ввод
2
Florida 25
Pennsylvania 23
11
Florida Gore
Pennsylvania Gore
Florida Bush
Pennsylvania Gore
Pennsylvania Bush
Florida Gore
Pennsylvania Gore
Florida Bush
Pennsylvania Gore
Florida Bush
Pennsylvania Gore

Вывод:
Bush 25
Gore 23
3
Florida 5
Pennsylvania 4
Alaska 3

Ввод:
4
Florida Gore
Pennsylvania Obama
Pennsylvania Clinton
Alaska Bush

Вывод:
Gore 5
Clinton 4
Bush 3
Oba
```

Примечание к примерам тестов

В Florida 2 избирателя голосует за Gore и три избирателя за Bush, поэтому 25 голосов выборщиков от Florida получает Bush. В Pennsylvania побеждает Gore (5 голосов против 1), поэтому Gore получает 23 голоса выборщиков от Pennsylvania.

В Florida побеждает Gore (5 голосов выборщиков), в Alaska — Bush (2 голоса выборщиков). В Pennsylvania два кандидата набрали наибольшее число голосов (по 1), поэтому 4 голоса выборщиков от этого штата получает Clinton, т.к. он идет раньше в лексикографическом порядке.

Мой код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <set>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <stack>
#include <queue>
#include <deque>
#include <iterator>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;

using lli = long long;
using lld = long double;
using ulli = unsigned long long;
using usi = unsigned short;

int main()
{
    //Государственные выборы по штатам
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    map <string, pair<int, string>> m_states;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        string state;
        int votes;
        cin >> state >> votes;
        m_states[state] = make_pair(votes, "");
    }

    //Штатные выборы
    int m;
    cin >> m;
    map <pair<string, string>, int> map_voters;
    for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i)
    {
        string state, candidate;
        cin >> state >> candidate;
        ++map_voters[{state, candidate}];
    }

    //Какой чел в каком штате выйграл
    auto it_voter = map_voters.begin();
    for (auto& state : m_states)
    {
        string max_candidate_name;
        int max_candidate_votes = -1;
        for (; it_voter != map_voters.end() && it_voter->first.first == state.first; ++it_voter)
        {
            if (it_voter->second > max_candidate_votes)
            {
                max_candidate_votes = it_voter->second;
                max_candidate_name = it_voter->first.second;
            }
        }
        state.second.second = max_candidate_name;
    }

    //формирование ответа
    map <string, int> m_res;
    for (auto state : m_states) m_res[state.second.second] += state.second.first;
    multimap <int, string> mm_res;
    for (auto candidate : m_res) mm_res.insert({ candidate.second, candidate.first });
    vector <pair<string, int>> vec_res;
    for (auto it = mm_res.end(); it != mm_res.begin();)
    {
        --it;
        vec_res.push_back({ it->second, it->first });
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < vec_res.size(); ++i)
    {
        set <pair<string, int>> st_temp;
        bool flag = 0;
        while (i + 1 < vec_res.size() && vec_res[i].second == vec_res[i + 1].second)
        {
            st_temp.insert(vec_res[i]);
            st_temp.insert(vec_res[i + 1]);
            ++i;
            flag = 1;
        }
        for (const auto& elem : st_temp) cout << elem.first << " " << elem.second << endl;
        if (flag) i++;
        if (i < vec_res.size()) cout << vec_res[i].first << " " << vec_res[i].second << endl;
    }
    set <string> st_zero;
    for (auto a : map_voters)
    {
        bool flag = 0;
        for (auto b : mm_res)
        {
            if (a.first.second == b.second) flag = 1;
        }
        if (!flag) st_zero.insert(a.first.second);
    }
    for (auto elem : st_zero) cout << elem << " " << 0 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Это задание с какого-то сайта? Можно ссылку?

Comment: https://edu.sirius.online/#/course/961

Comment: не знаю, откроется ли у вас, но это крч сириус.курсы

Answer (score 0):

Пример 1 - неправильный вывод в конце
Ввод

```
3
Florida 5
Pennsylvania 4
Alaska 4
5
Florida Gore
Pennsylvania Obama
Pennsylvania Clinton
Alaska Bush
Alaska Obama
```

Вывод

```
Gore 5
Clinton 4
Bush 4
Obama 0
Obama 0
```

Пример 2 - неотсортированный вывод кандидатов. У кандидатов одинаковое количество голосов, а вывелись они не в лексикографическом порядке. При выводе используется сортировка по имени штата, а не по имени кандидата.
Ввод

```
3
Florida 4
Pennsylvania 4
Alaska 4
5
Florida Gore
Florida Bush
Pennsylvania Obama
Pennsylvania Clinton
Alaska Obama
```

Вывод

```
Obama 4
Clinton 4
Bush 4
Gore 0
```

Comment: Код изменил, ваши тесты проходит, но система всё равно ругается

Comment: Значит делайте ещё тесты. Пробуйте другие комбинации.